# Scala equivalent of Java `Class` class?

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

In Java, there is a `Class<T>` class that represents, well, classes. It's useful when you need to do some class checks dynamically at runtime, for example, if some interface can accept varied number of arguments and it expects the arguments to have specific types: then the interface can return a list of `Class` objects to specify its requirements.

Apparently, it's available in Scala as well, but just as an alias to the Java class). Is it OK to use this in Scala (or in general, the `Class` class, in pure Scala code), or would there be a more idiomatic way to achieve the same thing there?

For more context, this is what I'm thinking of:

```
trait BuiltInFunction[Node] {
  def symbol: String
  def arity: Int
  def argumentTypes: List[Class[Node]]
  def apply(args: List[Node]): Node
}
```

`BuiltInFunction` represents functions that each can have different number of arguments and expect the arguments to be different subtypes of `Node`. If the system encounters a function, it will make sure that it's applied to arguments of proper types (as defined by `argumentTypes`) by calling the `apply` method with those arguments.

Is using `Class` the right way to do it in Scala?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: While the use of `Class` is valid in **Scala**, _relfection_ is not that common and usually there are other alternatives which are faster & safer. Would you mind explaining what do you want to do?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, didn't I explain enough in the question? What else would you like to know?

Comment: @siledh Why do you want to abstract over functions? What is the end goal? Will the functions will be constructued in runtime or in compiletime?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I'm writing a toy interpreter of a functional language. This abstraction is for a set of built-in functions (that I want to have a flexibility to easily define in my code). Anyway, just after writing the question I realised I won't need this, since the types would be checked before the interpretation so I can just cast the nodes and assume the cast will succeed. But the question is still interesting I think, I would be glad to know how to do this kind of thing in Scala.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need Scala-specific details (differentiating between properties and methods, implicits, etc.) using `Class` is perfectly fine; if it wasn't, it wouldn't be available in `scala.Predef` as an alias!

If you do, there is [Scala reflection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html) but to be honest, in my experience it's harder to use than the Java `Class`-based reflection. If you can use both I'd prefer `Class`.

OTOH:

1. `List[Class[Node]]` is not correct if you

   > expect the arguments to be different subtypes of Node

   It should be `List[Class[_ <: Node]]` instead.
2. `Class` only reflects classes after erasure, e.g. `classOf[List[String]]` and `classOf[List[Int]]` are the same. If you need to differentiate them `Class` won't be enough.